# Including template pages within another template?

Tags: templates, get-template-part

I've created a vertical page template which displays stacked sections (which are simply the content from other wordpress pages). I am having problems displaying the contents of pages which are themselves using templates.

This is the main query I am using to fetch the contents of other pages:

```
<?php
//change to the title of the pages you want to feature
$page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
$page_data = get_page($page);

// Displays the content
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
```

This works fine for most of the pages, except those which rely on templates themselves. I "think" I need to include something about "get template part", but I am not experienced enough to understand how to use in this situation and could use some help?

Thanks

Comment: Add some information/code about your actual query/loop and the template file(s) you're using to achieve this. So far one pretty much has to guess your approach.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`get_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) has been **deprecated**, don't use it anymore, use [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) instead. [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) returns an object by default, you can change this by altering the `$output` parameter, which you can use like you did. Although `get_post()` can take an object as `$id` parameter I personally prefer inputing the ID, but that actually shouldn't matter.

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
$page_data = get_post( $page->ID );

echo $page_data->post_content;
```

What you're describing - at least based on the code in your question - should have nothing to do with templates or the `get_template_part()` function, because the `post_content` you're getting is independent from that. The case would of course be different from that, if what your are missing from those pages you talk about **isn't** actually part of the `post_content`, but your question isn't indicating that.

Comment: Thankyou very much for updating my code. Now using get post instead. I'm afraid you are correct about "if what you are missing from those pages isn't part of the post content". The templates I am having trouble with involve filling in details in metaboxes eg. list number of posts, categories, thumbnail size etc and DO NOT FORM PART OF THE WP EDITOR POST CONTENT....  Any way to capture the page as wordpress & the template renders it??? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My example takes the pages from the navigation menu:

```
$menu_id = 2; //insert your menu id here
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);
if( !empty( $menu_items ) ){
    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item){
        wp_reset_postdata();
        if ($menu_item->object == 'page'){
            $post = get_page($menu_item->object_id);
            setup_postdata($post);          
            $template_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
            $template_name = str_replace('.php', '', $template_name);
            if($template_name == 'default') $template_name = 'tpl_default_page'; 
            ?>
                <div class="page-content">
                <?php get_template_part($template_name); ?>     
                </div>
            <?php
        }   
    }
}
```

Also your templates mustn't have `get_header()` or `get_footer()` in them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work (nothing displayed) on first go so will have to try again later :)

Comment: Be sure to change the $menu_id var to your menu id

Comment: Yeah - did that & removed the header / footer from the template - Cheers

Comment: Is this working now? @speedypancake

Comment: @ialocin - not yet...

Comment: @Madalin - having another go at this method. Nothing is displaying. Do I have to enter the name of the template of  the page I want to fetch is using anywhere? Also, I have added a <?php to the beginning of the code and closed it with ?> after the last brackets.

Comment: I forgot to mention to create a tpl_default_page.php where you enter the contents of page.php file from your theme without the get_header() or get_footer(); Also you can do a bit of debugging like after the second line you could do a `var_dump( $menu_items );` and see if you have anything there.